# Angula2 http.get subscribe issue

Tags: angular

The subscriber success in not working in my case , my service is

```
getProducts() : Observable<Product[]>  {
           return this.http.get("http://ipaddress.com:3000/api/v1/product")
                 .map(this.getResult)
                 .catch(this.handleError);
}

my controller is 

ngOnInit() { 
    this.products   =   this.homeService.getProducts().subscriber(response=>console.log("Hey i am your data"));

}
```

the subsciber success callback is not working  in my case

I imported libraries like this

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, Request } from '@angular/http';
import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx"
```

Comment: `subscriber` should be `subscribe`.

Comment: i consoled the constructor of both service and component , service constructor executes first and component executes second  , there is no console errors , but the problem is only when navigation to the home route , it works cool when reloading

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz TypeError: this.homeService.getProducts(...).subscribe is not a function now

Comment: That service method is a observable method eventhough i am getting the above error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `subscribe` instead of `subscriber`.

See this working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ANhHASY94iIFzT8BdMnr?p=preview

```js
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {HttpModule, Http} from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._http.get('https://httpbin.org/headers')
      .map(resp => resp.json())
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log(data)
      );
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your getting JSON out put to handle subscriber success.